# Remove a list of Special Characters from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, dataset, data-cleaning

I want to remove some characters (stored in a list) from all of the dataframe without iterating through rows.
[image]
I have this list:

```
speChars = ['[1]', '[2]', '[3]', '[4]', '[5]', '[6]', '[7]', '[8]', '[9]',
            '[10]', '[11]', '\[]', '\[', '\]', '\\n']
```

removed special characters from column names using this code:

```
for char in speChars:
  NASA_CAS_Data.columns = NASA_CAS_Data.columns.str.replace(char, '')
```

& now I want to delete all special characters in rows without mentioning all col names, tried `iloc` but it didn't worked because of `str`:

```
for char in speChars:
  NASA_CAS_Data.iloc[0:100, 0:100] = NASA_CAS_Data.iloc[0:100, 0:100].replace(char, '')
```

is there any simpler & faster way to remove special characters from all rows of a CSV dataframe in pandas?

## Answer

I'm somewhat new to StackOverflow & after editing my post, "Answer your question" button suddenly disappeared 
**I created a list containing names of the columns rather than using `loc` or `iloc` that cause** <*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'*>**, then iterated through it. I also forgot to use escape character `\` before the numbers! it was deleting all numbers too** (e.g. deleted 876 & [7] instead of just [7] from the first row & third column in the picture).
**final code:**

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/cleanedNASA.csv")

speChars = ['\[1]', '\[2]', '\[3]', '\[4]', '\[5]', '\[6]', '\[7]',
            '\[8]', '\[9]', '\[10]', '\[11]', '\[]', '[', ']', '\\n']

COList= df.columns.tolist()

for char in speChars:
  for col in COList:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(char, '')
```

Comment: Use `.replace(char, '', regex=True)`

Comment: resolved, thank you <3